# Unable to edit auto_master under macOS Mojave

Tags: osx, automounting, etc

I'm running macOS since several years and I have an `auto_master` file that contains my mounts config.

On a new Macbook, I cannot edit this file which is in the `/etc` folder and I have the following error: `"auto_master" E212: Can't open file for writing`. Note that I had already an `auto_master` file that I have deleted I don't know how (I had the same error message when trying to edit it) and that I can create files in the `/etc` folder.

Any idea how I can fix this issue?

Note: The error I have happens when I run `sudo vim /etc/auto_master` then I try to write the file. `sudo touch /etc/test_file` and `sudo rm /etc/test_file` work fine.

Comment: I should have mentioned that. The error I have happens when I run `sudo vim /etc/auto_master` then I try to write the file. `sudo touch /etc/test_file` and `sudo rm /etc/test_file` work fine.

Comment: Three first tests give `No such file or directory`. The last one gives `1`.

Comment: Note that I have an `auto_master\~` file and `ls -lO` command on it gives:
`-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  compressed 194  6 mar  2018 /etc/auto_master~`

Comment: Already tried to move `/etc/auto_master~` to `/tmp/` and create a new `auto_master` with no success. Followed your advice to remove `auto_master~` but with no success `touch: auto_master: Operation not permitted`. 
Cannot figure out what's happening.

Comment: I think the issue is that your terminal is not allowed to perform administrative tasks. I usually use iTerm2, where I got the same error. I started Terminal to copy auto_master back and MacOS asked me if I want to give Terminal administrative privileges, which I did. It worked.

Comment: That makes sense, I use iTerm2 and I did probably use it when having this issue.

Comment: I just ran into the same issue. iTerm2 does not have administrative permissions as lysium mentioned. Switching to the built in Terminal does the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by restarting in recovery mode, mounted the internal hard drive then copied the file. It's a workaround but it does not explain what's happening. Thank you very much Christopher.